# How can I access co-op skill games?

Tags: fifa-17

When I start exhibition games with a friend, we can play co-op skill games. We liked them so much, that we wanted to go pick which ones we wanted, but couldn't find the option anywhere. Are co-op skill games available to be played outside of pre-game?

Comment: I've thought the same thing!  I couldn't find them before.  I'll dive into this one.  I totally forgot about this

Comment: "You can go into skill games and do it from the main menu. I think when I did it, you had to scroll over with the RS to do mulitplayer. I believe it's offline only tho."  from https://fifaforums.easports.com/en/discussion/188860/can-you-play-multiplayer-skill-games-without-playing-a-match

You'll have to tell me how that turns out

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've been able to do it is by starting any kick-off, where a randomly generated MP skill-game starts up before the match.

The downfall is that you can't choose what skill game you want to play and you have to start over from the menu to begin another one.